# If Endor is a forest moon, where is its planet?

Tags: star-wars, ewoks

If Endor is a forest moon, where is its planet? It doesn't appear to be visible in *The Return of the Jedi* and I don't recall seeing it in the fantastic<sup>1</sup> Ewok movies.

---

<sup>1. I was 6 when I last watched the Ewok films and they may not be as good as I remembered.</sup>

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Endor_(planet)

Comment: Ah no, I believe it’s a moon *of a* forest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The planet Endor is not visible in *The Return of the Jedi*.**

> Endor, also known as Tana among the Ewok species, was the cyan gas giant planet orbited by the forest moon of Endor. The name "Endor" was also sometimes used for the forest moon. The planet itself was less well known than the moon.

The following is taken from an article on Wookieepedia and clearly shows that Endor, the planet, exists. However, it is not visible in [*The Return of the Jedi*.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Endor_(planet)/Legends)

> The planet Endor was never visible in any scenes in Return of the Jedi set on the forest moon's surface.

Given that it is considered a gas giant, and thus uninhabitable, it is logical that the planet would not be featured prominently in the movie or expanded universe.

[image: Ender is visible from the forest moon.]

Comment: The movie does not have the planet in it. Unless they've added it in another version

Comment: This screen shot is from Caravan of Courage

Comment: Updated. Sorry!

Comment: Why wouldn't the planet be shown if it was an uninhabitable gas giant? Gas giants are beautiful and make excellent film scenery. See for example the depiction of Jupiter in *2001: A Space Odyssey*.